# Javascript and Key Codes, preventing special characters in a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need some help with this JavaScript function.

I try to prevent some special characters in my textbox.

Aspx.vb code:

```
txtDes_OP.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "return IsAlphaNumeric(event);")
```

Code on aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
        specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
        specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
        specialKeys.push(36); //Home
        specialKeys.push(35); //End
        specialKeys.push(37); //Left
        specialKeys.push(39); //Right
        specialKeys.push(32); //Space

        function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {

            var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;

            alert(e.charCode);

            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));

            return ret;

        }

</script>
```

This Javascript function works, but it doesn't recognize code number 32 as KeyCode for Space key. So, now it's impossible to write two words separated by a space in my textbox.

According to this web page:
http://www.javascriptkeycode.com/
Number 32 is the key code for space key.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with this code javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function alphaNumeric(e) {
        tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (tecla == 8) return true;
        patron = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/
        te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        return patron.test(te);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `language="javascript"` what is this, 1999?